# Tirggering a get request is giving me a java.net.ConnectException: Connection Refused: connect

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

I have written a simple functional API test using RestAssured, org.JSON and testng. Here is my code:

What's interesting is everytime I run this test I'm getting the following error message:

When I copy the URL in my browser `http:/restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/norway` I'm always getting back results. So I dont think it's a firewall issue

```
package com.jaway.restassured.rest_assured;

import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.get;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import com.jayway.restassured.response.*;

public class AppTest {

    @Test()
    public void getRequestFindCapital() throws JSONException{

        //Make a request to fetch the capital of norway
        Response resp = get("http:/restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/norway");

        JSONArray jsonResponse =new JSONArray(resp.asString());
        System.out.println(resp.asString());
        String capital = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(0).getString("capital");

        Assert.assertEquals(capital, "Oslo");

    }
}
```

Here is the error message

```
FAILED: getRequestFindCapital
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at
```

Comment: Sorry but I think you missed a back slash: http: => // <= restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/norway

Comment: You error stacktrace Appear to be truncated, and then are you running the test on the same computer you are opening the page on the browser ?

Comment: oh my god ....this is so embarassing ....yes I missed a backslash